# Is there a way to reference and use C# libraries from a vb class?

Tags: c#, vb.net

One of my tasks for tonight is to take a logging class I made in another C# project and implement it in one of their vb projects. I have never touched vb and so am wondering if there is a way to possibly keep referencing my logging class which is in our enterprise library in C# or do I literally have to port it over as a separate vb class?

Comment: Are you talking about a compiled assembly or a source code file?

Comment: Most of the .NET base class library is implemented in C#, so you're already using C# libraries from VB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once any .NET project is compiled, it doesn't matter whether it's source was VB or C#.  They can be used by any .NET project as a referenced assembly, be it C#, VB, J#, Managed C++, etc.

Regardless of the source language, it's all compiled into the same IL code.

Comment: That makes sense. So I can use it but I have to implement it using VB still. Well at least there won't be more than one version of the same code.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your statement "I have to implement it using VB still". If I compile a VB project, I can then reference that assembly in any project that uses any .NET language.

Comment: For example my .dll was made in C#. I reference it in VB, from what it looks like, by using an `import` statement. Then from there since it is a vb project I have to use vb syntax to to actually call the methods and such.

Comment: Yes, that is the case.  You'd reference that assembly using VB just like any other call. Consider that you do not know what language the supporting .NET framework assemblies were written in (and we really don't care), yet we make references to them using whatever .NET language we wish.  Again, when everything is said and done, everything is compiled to IL code and then re-compiled to machine code at runtime.  It doesn't matter what language each assembly was originally written in. They all play together nicely.

Comment: Okay great. Makes alot of sense now.